# Regular Expression, find and replace Visual Studio 2015

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to write a regular expression that replaces a data annotation adding more paramter to it.

For example, 
Given this property

```
[DataMember(Name = "users")]
public List<User> Users { get; set; }
```

I would like to change it to

```
 [DataMember(Name = "users"), XmlNode("users")]
 public List<User> Users { get; set; }
```

Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: dont do this. because you may write [DataMember(Name = "users")] to [ DataMember(Name = "users")], [DataMember (Name = "users")], [DataMember( Name = "users")], [DataMember(Name    = "users")], [DataMember(Name =    "users")], [DataMember(Name = " users")   ], [DataMember(Name = "users"   )]

Comment: so better do do it manually, it wont take that much time

Comment: It will take time, because I have 20 classes and probably ~5 properties per class

Comment: You can use `(\[DataMember\(Name\s*=\s*"users"\))]` and replace with `$&, XmlNode("users")]`.

Comment: Do you want to do this for all `[DataMember(Name = "xxxx")]`? Only those immediately followed by `public List<User> Users { get; set; }`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

search with this regex:

`\[DataMember\(Name = \"(.*)\"\)\]`

and replace by this one:

`\[DataMember\(Name = "$1"\), XmlNode\("$1"\)\]`

[regex 101 link](https://regex101.com/r/ZnDeIR/2)

[image]